# UWP free docking library

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-standard, docking

Does it exists free library with docking layout control for UWP, like [Syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/sfdockingmanager/overview) or [Actipro](https://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/controls/universal/docking)?